# How many USB devices can my USB controller support?

Tags: usb

Is there any `lsusb` command or other program that can tell how many USB devices I can plug in before my USB 3.0 controller fails to accept them?

I know that 32 is the max devices per USB 3 controller. I want to know:

1. How many are connected per controller
2. How many are total supported
3. How many remaining endpoints/USB devices are available

Comment: `lsusb -t` will show you al hubs and the currently connected devices in a tree format.